# Twitter Widget Getting Error: Script error. Url: https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js Line Number: 0

Tags: twitter-widget

I have integrated twitter timeline widget to pull feed on my site, and after using javascript function window.twttr.widgets.load(). I can see feeds but on scrolling i am getting below error in console:

Error: Script error. 
Url: https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js 
Line Number: 0

And that is happening only in IE 11. Please help me resolving this issue.